# Invalid Django TIME_ZONE

Tags: python, django, timezone, django-settings, django-syncdb

Doing a recent build, I ran Django's syncdb, and I'm getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 252, in fetch_command
    app_name = get_commands()[subcommand]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 101, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/utils/functional.py", line 276, in __getattr__
    self._setup()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 125, in __init__
    raise ValueError("Incorrect timezone setting: %s" % self.TIME_ZONE)
ValueError: Incorrect timezone setting: America/New_York EST5EDT SystemV/EST5EDT US/Eastern
```

I haven't changed any of my core settings, so I don't know why I would suddenly be getting this error. The value in my settings.py file is `TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'`, which is a valid value according to [List of tz database time zones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name). Why isn't Django accepting this value?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

According to the error message:

> **ValueError: Incorrect timezone
>   setting: America/New_York EST5EDT
>   SystemV/EST5EDT US/Eastern**

it seems that `TIME_ZONE`, in `settings.py`, is equal to : `America/New_York EST5EDT SystemV/EST5EDT US/Eastern`

You must write only `America/New_York`.

If it's not the case, check for the existence of the file:

> **/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York**

if it's absent, that time zone is invalid on your system.

(valid time zones are in `/usr/share/zoneinfo/`)

Comment: You're quite right. A bug in my deployment script caused on old cached version of my settings.py to be used, which had this invalid TIME_ZONE value.

Comment: Please also note that the failing setting can be as subtle as `TIME_ZONE = 'America/New York'` instead of `TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'` That's what happened to me, and I had a two-year old version of Django.

Answer (score 0):

I got the error below. *I use **Django 4.2.1**:

> zoneinfo._common.ZoneInfoNotFoundError: 'No time zone found with key America/NewYork'

Because I set `'America/NewYork'` to [TIME_ZONE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#std-setting-TIME_ZONE) as shown below:

```py
# "settings.py"

TIME_ZONE = 'America/NewYork'
```

So, I set `'America/New_York'` to `TIME_ZONE` as shown below, then the error was solved:

```py
# "settings.py"
                      # ↓ "_" is added
TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'
```