# Error on running Django based MongoDB web admin

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I am trying to install Fan-of-Mongo a web admin for MongoDB which is based on Django I think.

I believe I have followed the instructions from here:

https://github.com/Fiedzia/Fang-of-Mongo

When I run this command:

```
python ./manage.py runserver
```

I get this error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.4.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 125, in __init__ raise ValueError("Incorrect timezone setting: %s" % self.TIME_ZONE)
ValueError: Incorrect timezone setting: Warsaw/Poland
```

Can anyone here give me an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750150/invalid-django-time-zone)

Comment: I have this error: ValueError: Incorrect timezone setting: Warsaw/Poland
I see Poland in /usr/share/zoneinfo/  but not Warsaw

Comment: Maybe that's the problem, like the other post says, if it's absent that time zone is invalid on your system. Try with another language and see if that works

Comment: Seems like the current version in github has 'Warsaw/Poland' as the setting in settings.py ... pretty dumb!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct timezone for Warsaw is `Europe/Warsaw`. Just fix your settings.py.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because of the reason that it cannot find the timezone info inside `"/usr/share/zoneinfo/"`  directory. The following is the solution:

try whether the timezone present in the `/usr/share/zoneinfo/`  directory.

If the time zone is not present then go to fangofmongo extracted directory and open **form/settings.py**   change the `TIME_ZONE = 'America/North_Dakota'`  (America/North_Dakota) these should be in your `"zone info"` directory